# Alpha channel for SKShader shader.fsh is ignored

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, glsl

```
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
}
```

Such an example renders a red rectangle, but the alpha is equal to zero. Why?
How can I render a semitransparent object?

[image]

Comment: You have to enable blending. Did you do that?

Comment: No. What should I write for SKShader?

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's documentation (emphasis added):

> This function must set the gl_FragColor variable to a color value to use in the blend stage. Typically, the color value you return in this variable should already be ***premultiplied*** by the fragment’s alpha value.

So if you want full red at alpha=0.5, use `vec4(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5)`

Documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshader/creating_a_custom_fragment_shader

See also this previous answer: [Shader with SpriteKit only register alpha for black color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61331357/shader-with-spritekit-only-register-alpha-for-black-color)

Comment: Your example has `vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`, which is not premultiplied alpha form.  Fully transparent red is `vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`.  You tried that?

Comment: vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) is a black color with 0-alpha

Comment: Premultiplied alpha format means you have to multiply R, G, and B with alpha when returning the result.  `vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` is the fully-transparent result for any color with alpha=0.  If you want full red `vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)` at alpha=a, then you should return `vec4(1.0*a, 0.0*a, 0.0*a, a)`.